# Подскажите пожалуйста ,ошибка при циклическом сдвиге

Tags: c++, массивы, циклы, матрицы

я попытался сделать

> Все нечетные строки матрицы сдвинуть циклически на К элементов влево.

но получилось так что оно сдвигает вправо ,в чем моя ошибка ?Прошу прошения если мой вопрос оформлен не правильно ,но я новичок )

```
for(i=1;i<string;i+=2)
{
    for(shift=0;shift<K;shift++)
    {
        tmp=Matrix[i][column-1];
        for(j=column-1;j>0;j--)
        {
            Matrix[i][j]=Matrix[i][j-1];
        }
        Matrix[i][0]=tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Matrix[i][j - 1] = Matrix[i][j];
```

Соответствено, поправить диапазон значений счетчика и направление цикла.

---

> ни как не могу понять что менять

```
tmp = Matrix[i][0];
for (j = 1; j < column; j++)
{
  Matrix[i][j - 1] = Matrix[i][j];
}
Matrix[i][column - 1] = tmp;
```

Comment: Cпасибо ,а какой цикл исправлять ?

Comment: @ОлегСтарков Внутренний.

Comment: @ Igor , прошу прошения ни как не могу понять что менять (

Comment: @ Igor ,cпасибо вам огромное ,сейчас буду разбираться )